# Is there a good WikiField for django models?

Tags: django, django-models, wiki

Is there a simple way I can add a "WikiField" to a model I have in my application?

I think the most important requirements are:

- A text field that can be added to any model.
- simple wiki markup or editor widget that enables text formatting and easy insertion of links and images.
- saves revision history with author information, and easily allows reverting back to any previous version.

Just to explain what I'm trying to do: Imagine you have a bookstore app. Most of the Book model's data come from the store's catalog. Now we would like to add a block of text that is a community wiki, so that users can write the plot summary for example.

Comment: And I really tried to search for this, but searching for combinations of "djago" "model" "field" and "wiki" is just too generic...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a combination of [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) and [django-tinymce](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce), or [Markdown](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown) if you prefer writing markdown?

I've not come across any field types specifically for Wikis, but with those components writing one really shouldn't take too long.